How may I install an Android System Image not available on Google Downloads?
I happened to be working on an Android application written around 2010 or so and the target OS is Android Cupcake. The application was written for very old hardware and still runs fine on those (it is still currently in use).
I am hired to write a new feature for this application and from the description of this feature, it should run flawlessly. But I can’t seem to find the right tools that will make my job easy.
I badly want to use Android Studio because I am used to it. But Android Studio doesn’t have Android Cupcake system image for x86 processor (in those days, Android was written for ARM processor only). I have an x86 Android Cupcake system image that works (please don’t ask how I got it because it is a very long story). I want to setup an AVD and use this image as the underlying system image but I’m lost.
Has anyone done this before?

I think this belongs on Stack Overflow

Finding an emulator can be hard if the hardware platform is so ancient. As this seems to be a special environment why haven't your customer provided you at least one of those special hardware systems? Getting an old adb version for accessing it would be way easier. As Android 1.5 is long discontinued by Google nobody can expect you to do computer archeology to find those old tools and then even make them run again.

I have the hardware, I have a working system image. If I can get this to work with Android Studio @Robert, then I’ll have all I can ever need (no need for the hardware at least for now)

Possibly related/dupe: Run custom ROM on emulator/VM

I also found more resources @AndrewT.: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/35079456/16770846". Since I’m not seeking to build a new ROM but I just want to add an AVD that will use this specific system image, can you write an answer for posterity? (This question gets a ton of traction but doesn’t have any useful answer.)

@ChukwujiobiCanon as I don't have first-hand experience with the issue, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to best answer it. Feel free to post an answer instead.

Do realize that Android 1.5 (Cupcake) predates even HAXM and the current hypervisor supported emulators. From what I remember it was QEMU based and translated ARM code to x86 at the software level so not great performance on a period PC hardware (1). I'm curious if modern Android Studio even connects to such a device due to changes in the AUTH handshake

Why yes I'm aware of all these. Curiosity led me to ask this question @MorrisonChang. Nothing stops me from running on an actual hardware except that it's just not work efficient. I asked this question hoping to find someone that has actually done this (even though the chances of that are pretty slim). If Android 10 (Gingerbread 2.3.3) is perfectly supported on x86 platforms in Android Studio then maybe someone can plug in a system image to have other Android versions (just my optimistic thought).

I have a system image that works, but how do I plug it in?

The biggest problem is that your system image is for unknown specs, see: Why are there not generic phone OS installers? (duplicate) and Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROMs and related risks. Why are Android devices more brickable than PCs?. When building AOSP there is a specific build command for emulators which will add in appropriate drivers, but the HAL layer changed: https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hal/archive in 8.0

At best you can try to run an old x86 ISO like: https://archive.org/details/sjarb_android_1.6r2 in a VM like VirtualBox (see: https://www.android-x86.org/changelog.html) to see if it will work, but again how well the specs (screen size, connectivity, other OEM hardware/customizations) match is unknown.
